# How do you show an UIAlertView above the Apple Pay PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay

Using the standard UIAlertView code below will show the alert underneath the Apple Pay *PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController* sheet.

```
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Payment Error"
                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                           delegate:nil
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                  otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
```

How can I show it above the payment authorization sheet? Or is there a different way of presenting error messages for Apple Pay? I want to give specific error messages when the user enters an invalid shipping address.

Comment: how are you presenting the alert?  I do not know too much about applepay, but since it is a view controller, are you presenting the alert on the applepayviewcontroller's view?

Comment: Not sure about your deployment target. I think instead of `show`ing a `UIAlertView`, `present`ing a `UIAlertController` might be a better idea. As long as you have the reference to the `UIViewController` that you want to show alert on top of, this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a new callback in iOS 11 for

```
public func paymentAuthorizationController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment,
handler completion: (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void)
```

As you can see, the handler changes from

```
completion: (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void)
```

to

```
handler completion: (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void)
```

Starting with iOS 11 we will get a `status` with an array of `NSErrors` on the completion handler.

Have a look at [this year's session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/714/) for more details.

Answer (score 16):

You can't show UI elements on top of any `Remote View Controllers` because it could compromise the security of the system. This includes `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController`.

Read more about Remote View Controllers [here](https://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/)

Answer (score 10):

You can't show `UIAlertView` on the `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` because of the security of the system.

The entire UI of `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` is presented via a Remote View Controller. This means that outside the PKPaymentRequest you give it, it’s impossible to otherwise style or modify the contents of this view.

And for handle Apple Pay error you have to use `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate` delegate method to show payment is successfully complete or there are any error.

For show `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController`,
present payment view controller as:

```
PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *paymentVC = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:request];
paymentVC.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:paymentVC animated:true completion:nil];
```

- The customer approves the purchase using Touch ID (or, if that fails
  3 times, by entering their passcode).
- The thumbprint icon turns into a spinner, with the label “Processing”
- Your delegate receives the
  paymentAuthorizationViewController(_:didAuthorizePayment:completion:)
  callback
- Your application communicates asynchronously with your payment
  processor and website backend to actually make a charge with those
  payment details. Once this complete, you invoke the completion
  handler that you’re given as a parameter with either
  PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.success or
  PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.failure depending on the result.
- The PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController spinner animates into a
  success or failure icon. If successful, a notification will arrive
  from PassBook indicating a charge on the customer’s credit card.
- Your delegate receives the
  paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_:) callback. It is then
  responsible for calling dismiss(animated:completion:) to dismiss the
  payment screen.

[image: Error Screen]

[image: Error Screen]

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                       didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                                completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus status))completion {

    //=========================================
    //=========================================
    //    Call your api here for charge payment and according to that api result show complition as follow
    //========================================
    //========================================


    // Use your payment processor's SDK to finish charging your customer.
    // When this is done, call:
    completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess);

    // When this is Payment not completed, call:
//    completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusFailure);

    // When this is Supplied billing address is insufficient or otherwise invalid, call:
//    completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusInvalidBillingPostalAddress);

    // When this is Supplied postal address is insufficient or otherwise invalid, call:
//    completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusInvalidShippingPostalAddress);

    // When this is Supplied contact information is insufficient or otherwise invalid, call:
//    completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusInvalidShippingContact);
}


// Sent to the delegate when payment authorization is finished.  This may occur when
// the user cancels the request, or after the PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus parameter of the
// paymentAuthorizationViewController:didAuthorizePayment:completion: has been shown to the user.
//
// The delegate is responsible for dismissing the view controller in this method.
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An action sheet is a specific style of alert that appears in response to a control or action, and presents a set of two or more choices related to the current context. Use an action sheet to let people initiate tasks, or to request confirmation before performing a potentially destructive operation. On smaller screens, an action sheet slides up from the bottom of the screen. On larger screens, an action sheet appears all at once as a popover.

Provide a Cancel button if it adds clarity. A Cancel button instills confidence when the user is abandoning a task. Cancel buttons should always be included in action sheets at the bottom of the screen.

Make destructive choices prominent. Use red for buttons that perform destructive or dangerous actions, and display these buttons at the top of an action sheet.

Avoid enabling scrolling in an action sheet. If an action sheet has too many options, people must scroll to see all of the choices. Scrolling requires extra time to make a choice and is hard to do without inadvertently tapping a button.

For developer guidance, see the [UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontrollerstyle/uialertcontrollerstyleactionsheet) constant in [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller).